# How to rotate any graph by any angle about any point?

Tags: graphing-functions, rotations

How can I do exactly as the title asks? I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure this out. I watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPgq2AudoEo&t=1s) video, and I now understand how to rotate about the origin, but I tried using the same steps to find the equation for any point, using h and k to represent the coordinates of the "new origin", and I got lost. I got to [this](http://prntscr.com/gk1rmy) point, and have no idea how to simplify, or if its even possible at all.

Any help at all will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I wonder how this post did not get more upvotes... the queston asked is crucial

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a function you're working with? i.e $f(x)$ = something?

If so, you can translate the point you're rotating about to the origin, rotate and then translate back.

To translate vertically by $\pm k$, simply look at $f(x) \pm k$. To translate horizontally by $\pm h$, simply look at $f(x \mp h)$

As an example of translating, say we have the function $f(x) = (x-2)^2 + 4$ and we want to translate it so the point $(2, 4)$ coincides with the origin. Using the notation in the previous paragraph, $k = -4$ and $h = -2$. To take care of the vertical translation we look at $g(x) = f(x) - 4 = (x-2)^2$. To take care of the horizontal translation we look at $h(x) = g(x+2) = x^2$. Now our function has been translated to the origin. You can rotate $h(x)$ and then translate its rotated version vertically by $+4$ and horizontally by $+2$

Answer (score 0):

To use this method one should convert $y=F(x)$ form into two separate parametric equations of form $x=f(t), y = g(t) $. For example 
$$ y^2 = 4 f x ; \rightarrow x= ft^2, y=2 ft $$

Next, a translation and a rotation  through angle $\theta$ can be done as you know$ (x,y)$ shifts $(h,k)$ between required points.

$$ x_1= x \cos \theta - y \sin \theta+ h\, ; y_1= x \sin \theta + y \cos \theta + k. $$

Next, you can see yourself if eliminating $\theta$,( which can be done) is desirable or worthwhile.

Comment: This is similar to what I've done so far; I started by converting the equation into parametric form, then recombined later, but it just got long and complex. Is there a simple way to combine those two equations into a single equation?

Comment: Yes, by considering its intrinsic differential equation. When integrating you can choose any new displace ment and tangent slope

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the given graph is that of $F(x,y) = 0 $.  After rotation of a point $(x,y)$ by an angle $\theta $ about the point $(h, k)$, the rotated point has coordinates $(x', y')$ given by:

$x' = h + \cos \theta \ (x - h) - \sin \theta  \ (y - k) $

$y' = k + \sin \theta \ (x - h) + \cos \theta \ (y - k ) $

Now, we need to express $(x,y)$ in terms of $(x', y')$, and from the above two equations, we get

$x = h + \cos \theta \ (x' - h) + \sin \theta \ (y' - k) $

$y = k - \sin \theta \ (x' - h) + \cos \theta \ (y' - k ) $

Finally, substitute these two expressions for $x$ and $y$ into $F(x, y) = 0 $ you will get a new function $G(x', y') = 0 $.  One last step, is to remove the primes from $G$, to get $G(x, y) = 0 $ and the graph of this function is the rotated graph of $F$.